# Deploying Sinatra app to Passenger 4.0.0.rc6 by vlad. On production server it keeps requiring :development group in Gemfile

Tags: sinatra, passenger, gemfile, vlad-deployer

On production server Passenger(4.0.0.rc6 + nginx) keeps requiring the `:development` group in `Gemfile`. After manually commenting them out from `Gemfile` the app runs fine. Otherwise, Passenger would fail on starting the app because of the missing gems.

I checked the error page, it seemed Passenger was running in production mode:

```
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV)
production
```

Below are sources of my simple app, am I missing any setting to have Passenger work? Thanks.

Here is my `app.rb`, a simple sinatra app.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
get "/" do
   "Hello!"
end
```

I deploy it by vlad to production server. Here is the `config/deploy.rb`

```
require 'bundler/vlad'
set :application, "sinatratest"
set :domain, "server domain"
set :deploy_to, "path/on/server"
set :repository, "mygithub branch"
```

And my `config.ru`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

And `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
group :development do
    gem 'vlad', require: false
    gem 'vlad-git', require: false
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to my own question:

See the vlad part in [Bundler manual](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/deploying.html), `require 'bundler/vlad'` and create a new task which runs both `vlad:update` and `vlad:bundle:install` or insert `vlad:bundle:install` to the original `vlad:update` command.

If the server uses RVM then it needs to set the path of `bundle` explicitly either by `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in the vlad task or use the `vlad-extra` gem, see [this post](http://dennisreimann.de/blog/deployment-with-vlad/).

What I am doing to make it work:

In `config/deploy.rb`:

```
require 'bundler/vlad'
set :bundle_cmd, "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm && bundle"
```

In `Rakefile`:

```
namespace :vlad do
  desc "Run vlad:update and vlad:bundle:install"
  task :deploy => %w[vlad:update vlad:bundle:install]
end
```

On local machine run `rake vlad:deploy` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is

> require 'rubygems'

As I understand this means require all gems from Gemfile. For just require the Productiv gems with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
```

Source: http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rationale.html

Comment: Hi @sir-script, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it didn't fix my problem. But you are right that it is a bundler setting problem. I googled with fewer keywords (instead of those in this question's title and found a solution). 

From the [Passenger manual](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#bundler_support), before loading the application Passenger runs `bundle.setup` which loads `Gemfile`. What I missed is to run `bundle install --without development test` on server. This step creates `.bundle/config` such that Passenger can load gems correctly.